# Electron not loading preload script when application is built

Tags: node.js, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am fairly new to Electron and I am having an issue of the preload script after I have built the application (electron-builder).  I am upgrading the Electron version to 26.3 from a very old version.  The old version was using `nodeIntegration = true` and `contextIsolation = false` exposing renderer.  I am wanting to use contextBridge to communicate between renderer and Main like mentioned in the documentation.  I am setting the preload parameter in the browser window to the path where the preload.js script is located.

```
webPreferences: {
            webviewTag: true,
            plugins: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts', 'preload.js')
        }
```

When I run it locally it works, but when I build it it is not loading the script.  I realized that the path is different between Local development and when it is built.  So I added the preload script to the `esxtrResources` section of the package.json file.

```
"build": {
    "extraResources": [
      "./launcher/**",
      "./extraResources/**",
      "./scripts/preload.js"
    ],
```

I have also tried using "files" parameter in package.json and didn't work either.

```
"build": {
    "files": [
      "main.js",
      "./scripts/preload.js"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      "./launcher/**",
      "./extraResources/**"
    ],
```

When I build the application, I can see that the preload script was put into the resources directory of the application, but when I start the app, I get a white screen.  I put in extra logging to see how far I get through the process and I don't see any logs showing the the preload script was loaded.
I have also tried several different ways of getting the absolute path but have been unsucsessful.

```
__dirname
process.cwd()
process.resourcesPath
app.getAppPath()
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"./scripts/preload,js"` the comma instead of a dot?

Comment: Debugging details are missing. Do you get errors in the console? Is your HTML correctly loaded?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo `"./scripts/preload,js"`.  It is a dot and not a comma.  The only logs I can view are the console logs that I put in on main.js.  My HTML is using a <webview> tag to load in an external website.  I put in console logs into the preload.js script and I'm not seeing those entries.  The script works when I run the application locally in my development env (`electron .`).
We are using Electron as a wrapper around our web application.  The HTML is not loading from the webview tag.  All I get is a white screen and all of the application menus do not function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on.  Once I figured out how to display the dev-tools automatically when Electron loads, I was able to see the error and causing the application not to load.
I didn't know the preload script only allows requiring electron module.

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require('electron');
```

I found that out as soon as I was able to view the console.  I removed all of the other requires I had and the preload script loads correctly.
It was a newbie mistake.  Wanted to share this in case anybody else runs into this.